# java null pointer exception because of loading properties

Tags: java, properties, nullpointerexception

I get nullpointer exception when try to load properties from file.

I read some solution,

- putting property file next to the class
- loading with our without using GetClassLoader

No success

see the pic http://1drv.ms/1QIimmg

Load fails, not the access, what did I wrong ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cs

Comment: @Tunaki, it is not duplicate, it is not about what is the NPE it is about WHY. If you check the screenshot then you can see everything seems to be ok (Inputstream != null) but Inputstream.load throws the NPE when the file is exists and has valid content

Comment: I think you've just not initialized the `props` variable. You need a `props = new Properties();` before trying to use it in the constructor.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson thanks, what a mistake :( , this post really duplicate, can be deleted ...